# R using combn with apply

Tags: r, apply, combn

I have a data frame that has percentage values for a number of variables and observations, as follows:

```
obs <- data.frame(Site = c("A", "B", "C"), X = c(11, 22, 33), Y = c(44, 55, 66), Z = c(77, 88, 99))
```

I need to prepare this data as an edge list for network analysis, with "Site" as the nodes and the remaining variables as the edges. The result should look like this:

```
Node1    Node2    Weight  Type
A         B         33     X
A         C         44     X
...
B         C         187    Z
```

So that for "Weight" we are calculating the sum of all possible pairs, and this separately for each column (which ends up in "Type").

I suppose the answer to this has to be using `apply` on a `combn` expression, like here [Applying combn() function to data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192961/applying-combn-function-to-data-frame), but I haven't quite been able to work it out.

I can do this all by hand taking the combinations for "Site"

```
sites <- combn(obs$Site, 2)
```

Then the individual columns like so

```
combA <- combn(obs$A, 2, function(x) sum(x)
```

and binding those datasets together, but this obviously become annoying very soon.

I have tried to do all the variable columns in one go like this

```
b <- apply(newdf[, -1], 1, function(x){
sum(utils::combn(x, 2))
}
)
```

but there is something wrong with that.
Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Thanks to ThomasIsCoding, StephenK, and Yuriy Saraykin for three different ways to make this work. I can't really choose an accepted answer, since they all do the job in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a function and then `map` that function to all the columns that you have.

```
func1 <- function(var){
  obs %>% 
    transmute(Node1 = combn(Site, 2)[1, ],
           Node2 = combn(Site, 2)[2, ],
           Weight = combn(!!sym(var), 2, function(x) sum(x)),
           Type = var)
}

map(colnames(obs)[-1], func1) %>% bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using `combn`

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  combn(1:nrow(obs),
    2,
    FUN = function(k) cbind(data.frame(t(obs[k, 1])), stack(data.frame(as.list(colSums(obs[k, -1]))))),
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)
```

which gives

```
  X1 X2 values ind
1  A  B     33   X
2  A  B     99   Y
3  A  B    165   Z
4  A  C     44   X
5  A  C    110   Y
6  A  C    176   Z
7  B  C     55   X
8  B  C    121   Y
9  B  C    187   Z
```

Comment: Thank you very much! When I try to run your code, I get the following error: ` Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3 `

Comment: @NickG I think you have your `site` column as `factor` type. To address, you can use `obs <- type.convert(obs, as.is = TRUE)` first

Answer (score 1):

try it this way

```
library(tidyverse)
obs_long <- obs %>% pivot_longer(-Site, names_to = "type")
sites <- combn(obs$Site, 2) %>% t() %>% as_tibble()
Type <- tibble(type = c("X", "Y", "Z"))

merge(sites, Type) %>% 
  left_join(obs_long, by = c("V1" = "Site", "type" = "type")) %>% 
  left_join(obs_long, by = c("V2" = "Site", "type" = "type")) %>% 
  mutate(res = value.x + value.y) %>% 
  select(-c(value.x, value.y))


  V1 V2 type res
1  A  B    X  33
2  A  C    X  44
3  B  C    X  55
4  A  B    Y  99
5  A  C    Y 110
6  B  C    Y 121
7  A  B    Z 165
8  A  C    Z 176
9  B  C    Z 187
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! All of this worked, except that `as tibble()` after combn was giving me an error on inconsistent lengths (rows of length 6, values of length 3). So I found this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49784858/tidyverse-friendly-hack-on-combn] and managed to get it done without using combn: `sites <- obs %>%
  expand(Node1 = Site, Node2 = Site) %>%
  filter(Node1 != Node2)%>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(id = paste0(sort(c(Node1, Node2)), collapse = " ")) %>%
  distinct(id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-id)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combn` function:

```
combn(length(list1), 2, FUN = function(x) {
  setNames(identical(list1[[x[1]]], list1[[x[2]]]), paste(x, collapse = ", "))
}, simplify = FALSE)

[[1]]
 1, 2 
FALSE 

[[2]]
 1, 3 
FALSE 

[[3]]
 1, 4 
FALSE 

[[4]]
 2, 3 
FALSE 

[[5]]
 2, 4 
FALSE 

[[6]]
3, 4 
TRUE
```

You can remove the names and use `simplify` if you only want the final number with no details on indexes.